# OCD or transgender? Or mix of them?

Tags: anxiety, gender

I had to study over recent years on layman level, whether [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) in general vs "transgender self-perception" (clinical definition of gender dysphoria?) are separate phenomena or they overlap.

What about [genderfluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genderfluid) persons, which experience various self-thoughts and feelings over time?

In other words, how one can distinguish, **do they experience actual gender dysphoria or it's just OCD symptoms**? Or can they overlap?

I read lately these articles in particular, yet have hard time to grasp my mind:

1. [Assessment of Self-Perception of Transsexual Persons: Pilot Study of 15 Patients](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/281326/)
2. [Personality Disorders in Gay, Lesbian, Bisexual, and Transgender Chemically Dependent Patients](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1521-0391.2011.00155.x)
3. [Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder Presenting as Gender Dysphoria/Gender Incongruence: A Case Report and Literature Review](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2376060520306027)
4. [Case Report: Doubts and Pre-occupations About Being Transgender: Questioning One's Gender Identity or a Case of Obsessive-Compulsive Disorder?](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyt.2021.644114/full)

Comment: *"More recently, gender identity has become a topic of OCD doubt. As this case illustrates, though, not all gender identity-based doubt is OCD."* (In your 4th articles link)

Comment: ok, that tells towards "these two can overlap" case. thanks.

Comment: After some thought on this question, I have given you an upvote for a good question. While it can be seen to be controversial, the question is asking about the merit of an OCD diagnosis over gender identity-based doubts. Welcome to Psychology.SE 

Comment: With your last comment, I cannot properly answer your question, but from my understanding, you **can** have overlaps, but you can also have gender identity-based doubts without suffering from OCD, just as much as you can suffer from OCD without having gender identity-based doubts. It will be interesting to see answers to this